# Losing connection to devices over the weekend

Tags: routing, hp-procurve

We have a networking scheme such as:
10.1.0.0/16 
10.2.0.0/16 
10.3.0.0/16

Each network is associated with a switch.  Each switch connects to a layer 3 core switch that also acts as our router.

We have a plotter on the 10.1.0.0/16 network.  It is usually accessible by all other devices on the network.  Some time over the weekend the device lost connectivity to devices in other networks.  I was able to ping it from the 10.1.0.0/16 network but not the other networks and users were not able to print.  Double checked the plotter and the computer and they seemed fine.  I then looked at core switch and tried to ping from the core to the plotter.  It got a reply and the second it did, the device was reachable by the other networks again.

Why would this happen and how can I prevent it from happening again.  It has happened three times.

Comment: Sounds like something flaky with the MAC address table, either on the switches or on the router.